# Contour plot equivalent to Wolfram Alpha's

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a contour plot for a very specific function. The contour plot I've obtained through ggplot2 is quite similar to Wolfram Alpha's plot, although I'm not getting the same "grid-like" (white stripes) behavior as in the latter source.

How could I get similar white stripes like those if I'm not sure what those values are? Should I increase the amount of points?

[image: Wolphram Alpha's contour plot]

```
library(tidyverse)

v <- function(r, q){
  value <- pmax(0, 3 * q - 1 + r - 3*r*q)^2 +
    pmax(0, r - 3 * r * q)^2 +
    pmax(0, -2 + 2*r + 2*q - 2*r*q)^2+
    pmax(0, 2*q - 3*r*q)^2
  return(value)
}
  
r <- q <- seq(0, 1, 0.001)
vertices <- expand_grid(r, q)

vertices %>% mutate(v = v(r, q)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = r, y = q, z = v)) +
  geom_contour_filled()
```

Comment: I'm presuming you mean the contour lines and not the white stripes. I'm not sure what you mean exactly with 'grid-like behavior', but if you want to add the contour lines you just need to use `geom_contour_filled(colour = "black")` to add black lines.

Comment: I mean the white stripes, yes. I'm going to put that in the question!

Comment: What's the source material here?  Do you know if those lines are "real" or if they are artifacts?  When you solve for your `v()` function using `v(0,0)` (which is apparently in the "white line" area), you get 0.  The same goes for an area around that value.  So `v(4,4)` in the upper right quadrant is also 0, so it doesn't look like anything "special" occurs along those lines, which is why I ask if they are artifacts.  Also, check your function for `v()` - have you double-checked that you are using the right functions there?  Maybe there's something missing?

Comment: They are definitely real values. Those are the analytical solutions to a game theory problem. I'm wondering if this is related to some sort of finite precision limitation.